# SSH and unattended processes

Tags: ant, ssh, cron

I have an Ant build that will sometimes execute a 'git push' within a directory on my server.  I can do this fine interactively because it asks for the passphrase for my key, but this becomes problematic if you set up a cron job to run the build unattended.

Are there options for me beyond not using a passphrase? I've heard of using ssh-agent, but I've also heard for unattended processes that route won't work.  Does anyone have any recommendations for this, and perhaps an example of how to implement it?

I saw that someone suggested to run the cron as a daemon here:
[Accessing SSH key from bash script running via a cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671413/accessing-ssh-key-from-bash-script-running-via-a-cron-job) -- but I'm not sure how I could do that or put in my passphrase without compromising it by putting it in plain text, etc.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set yourself up for password-less login.

Use `ssh-keygen` to generate a public/private key pair with *no* password.  Append the public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server.

Then run `ssh -i /path/to/private_key server` to confirm that the password-less login is working.

Finally, [configure git to use that `ssh -i ...` command](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitTips#How_to_pass_ssh_options_in_git.3F).

As @mah suggests, you might want to create a specific `git` account on the server.  You add the public key to ~git/.ssh/authorized_keys to enable the password-less login.

authorized_keys also has options to restrict what commands the incoming connection can run.  If you are interested in those features, read the SSH documentation.

And of course, you want to keep the private key file readable only by you.

Comment: What would be the advantages of creating a git account on the server?

Comment: Isolation.  The `git` account can be given access only to the data it needs to do its job.  So if anybody compromises the account (or your secret key), they can only mess up your git repository, not damage anything else.

Comment: Can you describe the setup with the git account, I'm still a little lost on this.  Where would the keys go, and how would I be able to run the ant build from the git account that's on the original account?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, was able to do it, I'll just need to find resources on how to constrict what that git account can do now.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by creating a restricted account on the git server and have the ant client use a keyless cert to that restricted account.

Comment: Can you describe this a bit more?  Also, the git repository is on my server as well, and I use SSH to push from my live site to the repository on a different subdomain.